# Put request with resteasy

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, resteasy, put

I want to construct a put request with resteasy that resembles the following curl command:

```
curl -u myUser:myP455w0rd! -X PUT "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/my-repository/my/new/artifact/directory/file.txt" -T Desktop/myNewFile.txt
```

I have started with something like

```java
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
ResteasyWebTarget rWebTarget = (ResteasyWebTarget) client.target(targetPath);
rWebTarget.register(new BasicAuthentication(user, password));

rWebTarget.request().put(entity);
```

I guess I have to specify the local file as `entity` but it is not clear to me how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to work in the following way:

```java
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
ResteasyWebTarget rWebTarget = (ResteasyWebTarget) client.target(targetPath);
rWebTarget.register(new BasicAuthentication(user, password));

InputStream stream = Files.newInputStream(path);

Entity<InputStream> entity = Entity.entity(stream, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
Response put = rWebTarget.request().put(entity);
```